rest api metric call to flink api not working
I'm trying to obtain the metrics of all the subtask of all the vertices, but I'm only able to get the metrics of the first vertices (i.e the source)
here is a snippet of my code
DataStream<EventBasic> mainStream = env.readFile(  new TextInputFormat(new Path(csvFilePath)), csvFilePath, FileProcessingMode.PROCESS_ONCE, 10)
                .setParallelism(1)
                .map(new MapFunction<String, EventBasic>() {
                @Override
                public EventBasic map(String line) throws Exception {
                    String[] parts = line.split(",");
                    if (parts.length == 3) {
                        String key = parts[0];
                        int valueInt = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);
                        long valueTimeStamp = Long.parseLong(parts[2]);
                        return new EventBasic(key, valueInt, valueTimeStamp);
                    } else {
                        return null;
                    }
                }
            }).setParallelism(1).assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(watermarkStrategy).setParallelism(1);





        DataStream<EventBasic> split = mainStream
                .partitionCustom(new RoundRobin(), value->value.key ) //any cast
                .process(new MeanPartialFunctionFakeWindowEndEvents(1000)).setParallelism(parallelism).name("roundRobinOperator");



        DataStream<EventBasic> reconciliation = split
                .process(new MeanFunctionReconcileFakeWindowEndEvents(1000,parallelism)).setParallelism(1).name("reconciliation");


pretty straight forward, I read a file, create a datastream, do a round-robin to process functions then reconciliate the data.
here is what I use to try and get the metrics
import requests
import time

# URL for Flink REST API
flink_url = "http://127.0.0.1:8081"
print("starting fake prometheus")

def get_running_job():
    response = requests.get(f"{flink_url}/jobs/")
    jobs_data = response.json()
    for job in jobs_data['jobs']:
        if job['status'] == 'RUNNING':
            return job['id']
    return None

def get_vertex_ids(job_id) -> dict:
    if job_id is None:
        return None
    metrics_url = f"{flink_url}/jobs/{job_id}"
    response = requests.get(metrics_url)
    metrics_data = response.json()

    vertex_ids = {}
    for vertex_data in metrics_data['vertices']:
        vertex_ids[vertex_data['name']] = vertex_data['id']
    print("vertex_ids: {}".format(vertex_ids))
    return vertex_ids

def get_vertices_metrics(job_id, vertex_ids):
    if job_id is None:
        return None
    for vertex_name, vertex_id in vertex_ids.items():
        subtask_ids = get_subtask_ids(job_id, vertex_id)
        print("vertex name: " + vertex_name)
        for subtask_id in subtask_ids:
            subtask_data = get_subtask_data(job_id, vertex_id, subtask_id)
            if 'errors' in subtask_data or subtask_data is None:
                print(f"Error in subtask data for vertex {vertex_name}, subtask {subtask_id}: {subtask_data.get('errors', 'Unknown error')}")
                return None
            print(f"Metrics for vertex {vertex_name}, subtask {subtask_id}: {subtask_data}")

def get_subtask_ids(job_id, vertex_id):
    if job_id is None:
        return None
    response = requests.get(f"{flink_url}/jobs/{job_id}/vertices/{vertex_id}").json()
    subtask_ids = [subtask['subtask'] for subtask in response.get('subtasks', [])]
    print("subtask names: " + str(subtask_ids))
    return subtask_ids

def get_subtask_data(job_id, vertex_id, subtask_id):
    request_string = f"{flink_url}/jobs/{job_id}/vertices/{vertex_id}/subtasks/{subtask_id}/metrics"
    print(request_string)
    response = requests.get(request_string).json()
    # print("data subtask")
    # print(response)
    return response

# Main execution
job_running = get_running_job()
if job_running:
    vertex_ids = get_vertex_ids(job_running)
    if vertex_ids:
        get_vertices_metrics(job_running, vertex_ids)
else:
    print("No running job found.")


I first get the running job id, then get the vertex ids then once I've got the vertex id I get the id of the subtasks, so far so good. I manage to get the subtask ids of all the vertices BUT I only get the metrics of the first vertex
here is an output of what I get
(base) cam_sophic@LAPTOP-1IDM703U:/mnt/c/Users/Camil/OneDrive/Documents/masters/memoire/flinkImplemProject$ python3 src/main/python/fakePrometheusBusynessPervertex.py
starting fake prometheus
vertex_ids: {'Source: Custom File Source': 'bc764cd8ddf7a0cff126f51c16239658', 'Split Reader: Custom File Source -> Map -> Timestamps/Watermarks': '20ba6b65f97481d5570070de90e4e791', 'roundRobinOperator': 'fa23e74564e1a1dc0cdbf2ab8d85bee8', 'reconciliation': '616e0cec5950ed9063934ee51dbd7955'}
subtask names: [0]
vertex name: Source: Custom File Source
http://127.0.0.1:8081/jobs/0712f75a286f3f511451c13dd14a1427/vertices/bc764cd8ddf7a0cff126f51c16239658/subtasks/0/metrics
Metrics for vertex Source: Custom File Source, subtask 0: []
subtask names: [0]
vertex name: Split Reader: Custom File Source -> Map -> Timestamps/Watermarks
http://127.0.0.1:8081/jobs/0712f75a286f3f511451c13dd14a1427/vertices/20ba6b65f97481d5570070de90e4e791/subtasks/0/metrics
Metrics for vertex Split Reader: Custom File Source -> Map -> Timestamps/Watermarks, subtask 0: [{'id': 'checkpointStartDelayNanos'}, {'id': 'Map.numBytesOut'}, {'id': 'checkpointAlignmentTime'}, {'id': 'Timestamps/Watermarks.numBytesOut'}, {'id': 'maxSoftBackPressureTimeMs'}, {'id': 'numBytesOut'}, {'id': 'Split_Reader__Custom_File_Source.numBytesOutPerSecond'}, {'id': 'mailboxLatencyMs_p999'}, {'id': 'buffers.inputQueueSize'}, {'id': 'Split_Reader__Custom_File_Source.numBytesOut'}, {'id': 'accumulateBackPressuredTimeMs'}, {'id': 'Split_Reader__Custom_File_Source.numBytesInPerSecond'}, {'id': 'numBuffersOut'}, {'id': 'accumulateIdleTimeMs'}, {'id': 'mailboxLatencyMs_mean'}, {'id': 'Split_Reader__Custom_F
ile_Source.currentOutputWatermark'}, {'id': 'buffers.outputQueueLength'}, {'id': 'numBuffersOutPerSecond'}, {'id': 'mailboxLatencyMs_p98'}, {'id': 'Shuffle.Netty.Input.Buffers.inputExclusiveBuffersUsage'}, {'id': 'mailboxLatencyMs_p99'}, 
{'id': 'Timestamps/Watermarks.numBytesIn'}, {'id': 'Map.numBytesIn'}, {'id': 'Shuffle.Netty.Output.Buffers.outputQueueSize'}, {'id': 'buffers.inPoolUsage'}, {'id': 'Shuffle.Netty.Input.numBytesInLocalPerSecond'}, {'id': 'numBytesInRemote'
}, {'id': 'mailboxLatencyMs_stddev'}, {'id': 'busyTimeMsPerSecond'}, {'id': 'buffers.inputFloatingBuffersUsage'}, {'id': 'currentInputWatermark'}, {'id': 'mailboxLatencyMs_p95'}, {'id': 'maxHardBackPressureTimeMs'}, {'id': 'Shuffle.Netty.
Input.Buffers.inPoolUsage'}, {'id': 'Split_Reader__Custom_File_Source.currentInputWatermark'}, {'id': 'mailboxLatencyMs_p90'}, {'id': 'numRecordsOut'}, {'id': 'mailboxMailsPerSecond'}, {'id': 'Split_Reader__Custom_File_Source.numBytesIn'}
, {'id': 'Timestamps/Watermarks.currentOutputWatermark'}, {'id': 'numBuffersInRemote'}, {'id': 'Map.numRecordsOut'}, {'id': 'buffers.inputQueueLength'}, {'id': 'Timestamps/Watermarks.numRecordsInPerSecond'}, {'id': 'Shuffle.Netty.Input.nu
mBuffersInRemote'}, {'id': 'backPressuredTimeMsPerSecond'}, {'id': 'mailboxLatencyMs_min'}, {'id': 'buffers.inputExclusiveBuffersUsage'}, {'id': 'numRecordsOutPerSecond'}, {'id': 'Timestamps/Watermarks.numBytesOutPerSecond'}, {'id': 'mail
boxLatencyMs_max'}, {'id': 'Shuffle.Netty.Input.numBuffersInLocalPerSecond'}, {'id': 'Shuffle.Netty.Input.Buffers.inputFloatingBuffersUsage'}, {'id': 'Shuffle.Netty.Output.Buffers.outPoolUsage'}, {'id': 'numBytesInLocal'}, {'id': 'numByte
sInRemotePerSecond'}, {'id': 'Shuffle.Netty.Input.numBytesInRemotePerSecond'}, {'id': 'Split_Reader__Custom_File_Source.numRecordsIn'}, {'id': 'mailboxQueueSize'}, {'id': 'buffers.outputQueueSize'}, {'id': 'Timestamps/Watermarks.currentIn
putWatermark'}, {'id': 'mailboxLatencyMs_p75'}, {'id': 'numBytesIn'}, {'id': 'Map.numRecordsInPerSecond'}, {'id': 'Timestamps/Watermarks.numRecordsOutPerSecond'}, {'id': 'Split_Reader__Custom_File_Source.numRecordsOut'}, {'id': 'Shuffle.N
etty.Input.numBuffersInLocal'}, {'id': 'numBuffersInRemotePerSecond'}, {'id': 'numBytesOutPerSecond'}, {'id': 'Split_Reader__Custom_File_Source.numSplitsProcessed'}, {'id': 'Timestamps/Watermarks.numRecordsOut'}, {'id': 'Timestamps/Waterm
arks.numRecordsIn'}, {'id': 'isBackPressured'}, {'id': 'softBackPressuredTimeMsPerSecond'}, {'id': 'numBytesInLocalPerSecond'}, {'id': 'Map.currentOutputWatermark'}, {'id': 'accumulateBusyTimeMs'}, {'id': 'idleTimeMsPerSecond'}, {'id': 'S
huffle.Netty.Input.Buffers.inputQueueSize'}, {'id': 'hardBackPressuredTimeMsPerSecond'}, {'id': 'Map.numRecordsOutPerSecond'}, {'id': 'Shuffle.Netty.Input.numBytesInLocal'}, {'id': 'Shuffle.Netty.Input.numBytesInRemote'}, {'id': 'Timestam
ps/Watermarks.numBytesInPerSecond'}, {'id': 'Split_Reader__Custom_File_Source.numRecordsInPerSecond'}, {'id': 'Shuffle.Netty.Output.Buffers.outputQueueLength'}, {'id': 'mailboxLatencyMs_median'}, {'id': 'Map.numBytesOutPerSecond'}, {'id':
 'Map.currentInputWatermark'}, {'id': 'Map.numBytesInPerSecond'}, {'id': 'numBuffersInLocalPerSecond'}, {'id': 'numBuffersInLocal'}, {'id': 'Split_Reader__Custom_File_Source.numRecordsOutPerSecond'}, {'id': 'numRecordsIn'}, {'id': 'numByt
esInPerSecond'}, {'id': 'Shuffle.Netty.Input.Buffers.inputQueueLength'}, {'id': 'Map.numRecordsIn'}, {'id': 'Shuffle.Netty.Input.numBuffersInRemotePerSecond'}, {'id': 'changelogBusyTimeMsPerSecond'}, {'id': 'buffers.outPoolUsage'}, {'id': 'numRecordsInPerSecond'}, {'id': 'initializationTime'}]
subtask names: [0, 1, 2, 3]
vertex name: roundRobinOperator
http://127.0.0.1:8081/jobs/0712f75a286f3f511451c13dd14a1427/vertices/fa23e74564e1a1dc0cdbf2ab8d85bee8/subtasks/0/metrics
Metrics for vertex roundRobinOperator, subtask 0: []
http://127.0.0.1:8081/jobs/0712f75a286f3f511451c13dd14a1427/vertices/fa23e74564e1a1dc0cdbf2ab8d85bee8/subtasks/1/metrics
Metrics for vertex roundRobinOperator, subtask 1: []
http://127.0.0.1:8081/jobs/0712f75a286f3f511451c13dd14a1427/vertices/fa23e74564e1a1dc0cdbf2ab8d85bee8/subtasks/2/metrics
Metrics for vertex roundRobinOperator, subtask 2: []
http://127.0.0.1:8081/jobs/0712f75a286f3f511451c13dd14a1427/vertices/fa23e74564e1a1dc0cdbf2ab8d85bee8/subtasks/3/metrics
Metrics for vertex roundRobinOperator, subtask 3: []
subtask names: [0]
vertex name: reconciliation
http://127.0.0.1:8081/jobs/0712f75a286f3f511451c13dd14a1427/vertices/616e0cec5950ed9063934ee51dbd7955/subtasks/0/metrics
Metrics for vertex reconciliation, subtask 0: []


sorry that it's not super neat, nonetheless we can see that we get the subtasks ids and the vertices. I also checked that the partial process functions indeed would all receive values which is the case.
